# r time range plot before and after

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, range

May goal is to generate a time range plot like this.

[image]

This is the toy dataset

```
Group1  N       Year
A      10(10)   1999-2001
B      83(56)   2001-2004
C      100(94)  2006-2007
D      53(51)   2009-2011
E      20(19)   2012-2012
F      142(141) 2015-2016
G      34(32)   2015-2017
H      45(45)   2014-2018
I      21(19)   2016-2017
J      82(53)   2017-2019
K      12(12)   2021-2021
```

The goal is to show time below 2016 in blue, time above 2016 is red, time that overlap the before-after 2016 (groups G, H) in shade of blue before 2016 and shade of red after 2016. Also the label on top of each plot based on values in column N.

I have tried few things with geom_errobar but things got out of control. Any help on how to accomplish this is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for a dumbbell plot using the `ggalt` package:

```
library(ggplot2)
#install.packages("ggalt")
library(ggalt)  # For geom_dumbbell
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  separate(Year, into = c("StartYear", "EndYear"), convert = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(Color = ifelse(StartYear < 2016 & EndYear > 2016, "overlap", 
                        ifelse(EndYear <= 2016, "before", "after"))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = StartYear, xend = EndYear, y = Group1, yend = Group1, colour = Color)) +
  geom_dumbbell(size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(x = (StartYear + EndYear) / 2, label = N, vjust = -1)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev)+
  geom_vline(xintercept = 2016, linetype = "dotted", color = "purple" , linewidth = 1)+
  scale_colour_manual(values = c(before = "blue", after = "red", overlap = "purple")) +
  labs(title = "Time Range Dumbbell Plot", x = "Year", y = "Group", colour = "Period") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]